# Azure Scheduled WebJob Never Finished Status

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a scheduled web job that runs a function every minute:

```
[TimerTrigger("00:01:00", RunOnStartup = true)]
```

Sometimes it hangs and has a "Never Finish" status for a few days. This prevents new schedules for the job to be triggered. The Azure log also didn't record any entries - log was empty for that run.

I wonder if there is a way to tell Azure scheduler to continue with the scheduling if the job has a "Never Finish" status / state? Does setting "UseMonitor = true" do this?

Comment: A Timertrigger web job should be continuous, not triggered.

Comment: @RobReagan Its continuous and scheduled - sorry my wording is wrong. If a scheduled run is in the "never finished" state, Azure doesn't seem to schedule new runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, if the scheduled web job processing is taking a long time periodically (or not finishing at all), it must be that every now and then the operations in your job function take a long time or fail. All depends on what your job is actually doing internally. If it is going async in places, the SDK will continue to wait for it to return.

According to this, I suggest you could try to use webjob's TimeoutAttribute.
It easy for functions to be cancelled based on timeout if they're hung.It will show a exception.

If you find the error is too much and you want to alter, I suggest you could use ErrorTrigger, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to.md#errors).

More details, you could refer to below codes.

I used the queue to test it, the result is as same as TimerTrigger webjob.

```
  //Change the function timeout value
        [Timeout("00:00:03")]
        public static void  TimeoutJob(
        [QueueTrigger("queue")] string message,
         CancellationToken token,
        TextWriter log)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("From function: Received a message: " + message);

            Task task = new Task(new Action(() =>  /*here is your code*/ Thread.Sleep(5000)), token);
            // this will cancel the task is the token is CancellationRequested and show the exception the task is cancel
            task.Wait();
             Console.WriteLine("From function: Cancelled: Yes");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are there any ways to cancel the job without passing the cancellation token? Otherwise every async method called by the job will need to have its signature changed.

Comment: If I set the schedule time to greater than 1 min, "Use Monitor" is enabled. Does "Use Monitor" spawn another instance of the job when the time is up if the previous job hangs?

Comment: As far as I know, the timeout attribute is the best way to cancel the webjob function. Without using this, you need write your own code to monitor your webjob's status.

Comment: Use Monitor keeps track of executions by keeping track of execution history in storage, ensuring that schedules can be maintained in the face of process crashes or node restarts. It uses this history to "catch up" on missed schedule executions, if for some reason an occurrence was missed. If your function execution takes longer than the timer interval, another execution won't be triggered until after the current invocation completes. The next execution is scheduled after the current execution completes.

Comment: Link is broken, can we get an updated article link? Thanks.